# VSCode auto import not recognising eslint alias/webpack resolve/tsconfig paths

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, eslint, auto-import

I have an node module which I want to create an alias for.

I have the following configs:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "paths": {
            "@my-lib/*": [
                "node_modules/my-lib/src/Components/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


// webpack.config.js
resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.ts'],
        alias: {
            '@my-lib': path.resolve(
                './node_modules/my-lib/src/Components'
            ),
        }
    },

// eslintrc.json
"settings": {
        "import/parsers": {
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            "typescript": {},
            "alias": {
                "map": [
                    [
                        "@my-lib",
                        "./node_modules/my-lib/src/Components"
                    ]
                ],
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
            }
        }
```

But when importing a module from my-lib vscode auto import resolves it to:
`my-lib/src/Components/...`

Another config I have is:
`"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",` (though I've tried auto and non-relative as well)

I tried pretty much every combination of `baseUrl` and `paths`.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hey, I know this question's 9 months old, but did you solve this in the end? I'm having the same issue